# Adding time duration of my build into Makefile

Tags: performance, makefile

I would like to add the build time duration of my Makefile build to the printout when the build is done..  something like this:

Build Duration:  1:23.45

I haven't been able to find anything about doing this but it has to be do-able.. Right now i print the time in which is completes with $(TIME), but i'd like to print how long the build took to complete. I am using clearmake.

Comment: Clearmake or GNU Make?

Comment: clearmake (though the clearmake kicks off a gnu_make as well during its procedure, but i think clearmake would be where I would want to do duration calculation and printout)

Answer (score 3):

The `time` binary supplies this functionality. You need to specifically execute it to bypass any time command built into your shell (as in bash):

```
/usr/bin/time --format="Build Duration: %E" make
```

Answer (score 0):

quite old question, maybe someone interested

please consider next makefile example

```makefile
$(DEBUG).SILENT: ; # no need for @, DEBUG=yes make ... disable silence
.ONESHELL: ;       # when a target is built all lines of the recipe will be given to a single invocation

TIMER_START  := $(shell date "+%s")
TIMER_END     = $(shell date "+%s")
TIMER_SECONDS = $(shell expr $(TIMER_END) - $(TIMER_START))
TIMER_FORMAT  = $(shell date --utc --date="@$(TIMER_SECONDS)" "+%H:%M:%S")

.PHONY: sleep
sleep:
    sleep 5

.PHONY: timer
timer:
    echo "Build Duration: $(TIMER_FORMAT)"
```

expected results

```bash
$ make timer
Build Duration: 00:00:00
$ make sleep timer
Build Duration: 00:00:05
```