# Show the build duration time in Makefile

Tags: makefile

within in Make file,  i can printed the time before the build start and finished.

```
myitem:
    printf 'start time is %s\n' "$$(date --iso-seconds)"
    #other build command, i.e. g++ xxxx.cpp
    printf 'end time is %s\n' "$$(data --iso-seconds)"
```

Is there any other way that implemented like below in Make file?

```
myitem:
    starttime = $$(date)
    #start my build
    printf "The build took time:" NowTime - startTime
```

Comment: I don't think there is a built-in way to do it. You have to use external tools such as the 'time' program in Unix. As far as I know there is no native similar Windows command, but there must be a powershell or some port of Unix command available.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15171305/adding-time-duration-of-my-build-into-makefile

Comment: You can defined `SHELL = time` or similar, and you have a recent GNU Make, `.ONESHELL` to have recipes be executed (and timed) as a whole.

Comment: @reinierpost `SHELL = time` is an interesting idea, if only you could provide a working example. It would still break `$(shell ...)` GNU Make function, though.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin Good point ... I didn't test it, and `time` fails because it doesn't take a `-c` option. So a wrapper script would need to be written that calls `time sh "$@"` or does something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is just for informational purposes, the absolutely easiest way is to run your build under the `time` command.

To answer your question in full, though, read on.

By default, each line of a recipe runs in a separate shell instance.  To use a variable from an earlier command, use a single shell.  Perhaps like this:

```
myitem:
    d=$$(date +%s)\
    ; build \
    && echo "Build took $$(($$(date +%s)-d)) seconds"
```

The backslashes escape the newlines so that this is seen as a single long logical line by `make`. The semicolons and `&&` are statement separators - I find it helpful *(because* it's so ugly!) to put them at the beginning of the next line just to remind myself that this is a single compound command. If the build fails, the stuff after `&&` will not execute; this is slightly inelegant, but better than thinking that your build succeeded when it didn't.

I switched to `date +%s` (seconds since epoch) because that is so much easier to work with programmatically.

In GNU Make, you could also use [.ONESHELL](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/One-Shell.html).

Comment: There is a more elegant way, IMO, https://stackoverflow.com/a/37726101/412080

Comment: ... Like the first paragraph says.

Comment: More elegant way by using a GNU Make function. Unlike your 1st paragraph.

Answer (score 5):

One easy way is to prefix your commands with `/usr/bin/time`, e.g.:

```
/usr/bin/time --format="took %E" <the build command, i.e. g++ xxxx.cpp>
```

---

Another elegant way is to use `bash` functionality instead of `/usr/bin/time` or `/usr/bin/date`. And a GNU Make function to time any command line without cluttering it with heavy boilerplate. Unlike the accepted answer.

The following example `Makefile` times a `<cmd-line>` of a recipe by wrapping it into `$(call timeit,<cmd-line>)`. The only constraint is that `<cmd-line>` must not contain `,` symbol, which is used by the GNU Make to separate `call` arguments:

```
SHELL := /bin/bash # Use bash instead of default /bin/sh.
.SHELLFLAGS := -e -o pipefail -c # Make bash fail and report the 1st error in ;-separated lists or pipes.

timeit = @echo "$(1)"; t0=$$EPOCHSECONDS; $(1); echo "$(1). Took $$((EPOCHSECONDS - t0)) seconds."

all : test test_fail

test:
    $(call timeit,sleep 2)
    $(call timeit,sleep 1 | cat; true) # Handles pipes and lists.

test_fail:
    $(call timeit,false | cat; true) # false causes the recipe to fail, as it should.

.PHONY: all test test_fail
```

Running it outputs:

```
$ make
sleep 2
sleep 2. Took 2 seconds.
sleep 1 | cat; true
sleep 1 | cat; true. Took 1 seconds.
false | cat; true
make: *** [Makefile:13: test_fail] Error 1
```

---

However, prefixing your commands with `/usr/bin/time -v` or `/usr/bin/perf stat -ddd` can report resource usage information that cannot be easily replicated by `bash` alone.

Comment: It will only work if you have the `time` program; otherwise, it will not =/
The `time` will be just a keyword in bash and will not work in the makefile.

Comment: @voiski Note the full path to the command.

Comment: Exactly, it will only exist if you have the time program where is not always true like in some docker images. Try `type time` to see two places, the keyword and the program if you have it. Example with only keyword responding: `docker run --rm debian bash -c "time /usr/bin/time"`

Comment: @voiski `/usr/bin/time` is a pretty fundamental program. If you don't have it installed, complain to your system administrator, or use something else.

Comment: Sorry, I got the wrong tong here. My point is that it will only work if having the program, and that is passive of being only a keyword(docker images). To avoid confusion to the final user, can we add this alert in your answer? Like: `Please, ensure to have the time program installed in your environment. "time" is also a keyword in bash and may be missing in some docker images`

Comment: @voiski Added another method for you, requires only GNU Make and bash.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a late answer, but in case others are looking at it:  Another solution is to pipe your time to a temporary file, and do the difference there:

```
all:
    date +%s > _time_$@.txt
    sleep 3
    echo $$(($$(date +%s)-$$(cat  _time_$@.txt)))
    rm _time_$@.txt
```

This prevents having to merge all the recipes, which you might not want to do.

Comment: The syntax would likely have to be updated, but the concept is the same (write date to file, run command, and then echo the difference between the file's date and current date).

Comment: Though notice that the `rm` will not execute if the main command (here, `sleep`) fails; and the static temporary file name prevents parallel builds.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry @tripleee `$@` is a bare target filename only in examples and tutorials with one flat build outputs directory. Normally, it is a relative or full path with directories in it, so that file `_time_$@.txt` expands to a path with a non-existent top level directory. A fix is to `touch $@.start_time` to record the start time and later `stat --format=%Y $@.start_time` to read the start time. `$@.start_time` empty file doesn't get removed when the command being timed fails, but that is otherwise harmless and perfectly robust and race-condition free in parallel or concurrent builds.

Comment: A successful build removes any `$@.start_time` files left by failed builds.

Answer (score 0):

Write a simple wrapper script `/usr/bin/timebash.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
# For debug purposes: printf "'%s'\n" "$@"
/usr/bin/time /bin/bash "$@"
```

and add to your Makefile

```
SHELL = /usr/bin/timebash.sh
```

and you will automatically get runtimes for each command executed:

```
0.36user 0.14system 0:00.48elapsed 102%CPU (0avgtext+0avgdata 44032maxresident)k
```

Sample usage:

```
make -j 1 2>&1 | tee full.log
grep -Poh "\d+:\d+[.]\d+(?=elapsed)" full.log | sort -V
```